# Pygame time.get_ticks()

Tags: python-2.7, time, pygame

I have difficulty understanding what the description of the function exactly means:

**Return the number of millisconds since pygame.init() was called. Before pygame is initialized this will always be 0.**

Can any one explain this with maybe an example? I tested the following one time with screen and once without it. When the screen line comes before `get_ticks` i will have some ms-values around 130-150 and when the screen line comes after the ms-value is about 19-20 ms. Why?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

last=pygame.time.get_ticks()

while 1:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    print last
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have it the wrong way round.  It does exactly what you said: get_ticks() returns the number of milliseconds since pygame.init() was called.  I get 51 if get_ticks() is called before the screen is set up, and 210 after.  This is because of the time taken to set up the display.

Comment: So that means one should use `get_ticks()` as the last thing before entering the main loop? and the 17-19 milliseconds (or in your example 51) is the taken for pygame to be imported and initialized, am i right?

Comment: It depends why you are calling it.